# How to add a class to anchor that stand in first words of parent using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know jquery very well, and can't understand how to do it. Some code works, but not how I need it to.

That code must be:

```
<div class="page-content">
    <p> <a href="#">First</a> Sentence </p>
    <p> Second Sentence </p>
    <p> <a href="#">Third</a> Sentence </p>
    <p> Fourth <a>First</a> Sentence </p>
    <p> Fivth Sentence </p>
</div>
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```js
if(a is first word in paragraph) {
    /* do something */
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.page-content a').each(function(){  
            var pdata = $(this).addClass("red");
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: "Add class to anchor that stand in first words of parent"... ? For each paragraph, if there's an anchor at the very beginning of it, you want to add a class to it, is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.filter()` to filter selected elements. In callback function use [`.contents()`](https://api.jquery.com/contents/) to getting children of element and check that first index of it is text or not.

```js
$(".page-content p").filter(function(){
  return $(this).contents().get(0).textContent.trim() == "";
}).find("a").addClass("red");
```

```css
.red{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page-content">
  <p> <a href="#">First</a> Sentence </p>
  <p> Second Sentence </p>
  <p> <a href="#">Third</a> Sentence </p>
  <p> Fourth <a href="">First</a> Sentence </p>
  <p> Fivth Sentence </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.page-content a').each(function(){  
        var pdata = $(this).addClass("red");
        if($(this).parent().html().indexOf(($this)[0].outerHTML) == 0){
             //do something
        }
    }); 
});
```